# Why can't tcsh do a single-line 'which -> vim' command?

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh, csh

I often have to do which command, and then open it in vim to actually see what's inside. I'd like to have an alias or function that does this, with tab completion. Here's what I've tried:

```
superwhich() {
    which "$1" | vim
}

superwhich2() {
    vim $(which $1)
}
```

Neither of these work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The 1st is broken because it's passing the filename as *input* on stdin instead of command line argument to vim. The 2nd should work (except when the program name contains spaces). What errors do you get from it?

Comment: The second gives me 'Illegal variable name'.

Comment: Are you sure you running that in `bash`? There's no such error in `bash`. Please post some reproducible example.

Comment: Is your shell `csh` or `tcsh`? Then here's you superwhich alias: `alias superwhich 'vim \`which \!:1\`'`

Comment: With `zsh`: `superwhich() vim -- =$1` (which also handles nicely the case where the command can't be found or if there's also an alias/function by that name)

Comment: Yeah Zsh is great, it's my favorite shell. Unfortunately we're only allowed to use tcsh here.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy, that worked! Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csh` and `tcsh` don't have functions.

The only way is to use aliases, and pass arguments to them via `!` history substitutions:

```
alias superwhich 'vim "`which \!:1`"'

superwhich bzgrep
```

Or better (with error checking):

```
alias superwhich 'set q = `which \!:1`; if(-r "$q") vim "$q"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a script for that:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for cmd do
  if
    cmd_path=$(command -v -- "$cmd")
  then
    set -- "$@" "$cmd_path"
  else
    printf >&2 '"%s" not found\n' "$cmd"
  fi
  shift
done
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && vim -- "$@"
```

Then that could be used from any shell.

Note that it won't work for `sh` builtins (like `echo`/`[`...).

With `zsh`, you'd just run:

```
vim =cmd
```

Or

```
vim cmd(:P)
```

to edit the file of the `cmd` command.